# I mess up JSON object, arrays and strings

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, object

So i´m, trying send data from php to js.

**PHP**

```
$balkTypes[] = $stmt->fetchAll();
echo json_encode($balkTypes);
```

**JS**

```
balkTypesData = {}; //Outside Ajaxcall

success: function(result){
    balkTypesData = result;
    Console.log(balkTypesData);
}
```

**Console**

```
[[{"id":"3","typ":"Bas 200*600","hojd":"200","bredd":"600","rec":"","viktM":"135"},{"id":"2","typ":"Bas 240*600","hojd":"240","bredd":"600","rec":"","viktM":"160"},{"id":"5","typ":"Isol\u00e4tt 240*600","hojd":"240","bredd":"600","rec":"","viktM":"105"},{"id":"4","typ":"Kontur 240*600","hojd":"240","bredd":"600","rec":"","viktM":"105"},{"id":"6","typ":"Passbit","hojd":"0","bredd":"0","rec":"","viktM":"0"}]]
```

Now, i´d like to search my Json object?!
I´d like to find "viktM" for "typ:Bas 200*600"

```
//Get balkType weight/m
var searchField = "typ";
var searchVal = "Bas 200*600";
for (var i=0 ; i < balkTypesData.length ; i++){
   if (balkTypesData[i][searchField] == searchVal) {
     weigth = balkTypesData[i]['viktM'];
     console.log(weigth);
   }
}
```

First of all, it seams that i cannot use `.lengt`on "balkTypsData". it gives me 410 hits. Must be all characters?

Second, i cannot find how to access part of my object.
If i use: `console.log(balkTypesData[i][searchField]);`
I get: "Undefined"
I have also tried to remove the "[i].

So what am i missing?
Be gentle i´m still learning.

Comment: You are on the right track... look at `JSON.parse()` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you receive the data from your AJAX request it's not JSON, just a string.

The `length` result that you're getting is the `length` of the *string*, not the amount of elements within the array.

Furthermore you're setting `$balkTypes[]` which means that you're trying to add 1 entry in the array of `$balkTypes` however `$stmt->fetchAll();` also returns an array so you now have a nested array which is not needed.

In your PHP file change

`$balkTypes[] = $stmt->fetchAll()`

to

`$balkTypes = $stmt->fetchAll()`

this will make sure that when you fetch your data it will be an array containing all objects instead of an array containing the array of objects.

Then in your JS, instead of trying to directly read from the string, use `JSON.parse()` to convert the *json string* into a collection of JS objects/integers/arrays/strings/booleans

e.g.

```
success: function(result) {
    balkTypesData = JSON.parse(result);
    console.log(balkTypesData);
}
```

**EDIT**

As pointed out by [Armen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5397059/armen) you could also set the `dataType: 'json'` in the AJAX request, when the AJAX request returns it will automatically do the `JSON.parse()` so you can just directly `console.log(result);` to see the output.

Within the console.log you should now see the nested structure instead of just the string.

From here on your loop which checks the values seems correct and I would not change it unless it tells you that something is wrong.

Docs: [JSON.parse();](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: Very well explained. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [`$.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) (jQuery) or [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) (vanilla):

**With jQuery**

```
success: function(result){
    balkTypesData = $.parseJSON(result);
    console.log(balkTypesData);
    console.log(balkTypesData[i][searchField]);
}
```

**Without jQuery**

```
success: function(result){
    balkTypesData = JSON.parse(result);
    console.log(balkTypesData);
    console.log(balkTypesData[i][searchField]);
}
```

Comment: Oh, Thank you. Works very well!

Answer (score 1):

Set in your jQuery $.ajax request additional attribute `dataType: 'json'`

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: { params },
  success: function( response ) 
  { 
     // Your data will be already json no need to parse it
     console.log(response);
  }
});
```

Comment: oh, so i can just add "Datatype" on my ajaxcall... cool. Thank you.

Comment: Yes exactly `dataType: "json"` will consider that return information is json and you will have in result already json look here - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

You are **encoding** a JSON on the PHP side. You are not **decoding** it on the JS side.

You should look at [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)